# Find what amount of available space do I have on my linux machine

Tags: linux

I have a custom amazon linux distribution Linux ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx 4.9.85-38.58.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 14 01:17:26 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

And my **df** command looks like this:

[image: df command output]

As far as I can tell, my /dev/xvda1 filesytem is mounted on / and has 8Gb available (0% free). the filesystem devtmpfs is mounted on /dev and has 8Gb of available space(99% free) and tmpfs also has 8Gb of space and 100% free space so I guess I should have a total of 24Gb but if I issue a **lsblk** command to see my drives I get this:

[image: lsblk command output]

Meaning that I only have 1 8Gb drive attached, so what's going on?

Comment: tmpfs is a memory only ramdrive.

Comment: You should paste the text into the question, not add links to some images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `tmpfs` and `devtmpfs` are virtual memory based filesystem types, and are used by the operating system. They do not reside on your physical disk. Therefore, you only have 1 disk based filesytem, for "/".

You can read more about `tmpfs` here: [tmpfs man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/tmpfs.5.html)